# Unicode filenames with zeos / sqlite

Tags: delphi, unicode, zeos

I need to save data in sqlite databases with user-chosen filenames. This includes unicode filenames. Is there a way to specify this in the Zeos components in Delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ZeosLib people are working on getting Unicode support done, see this forum posting: [The next ZeosLib "generation" ... 7.x](http://zeos.firmos.at/viewtopic.php?t=2001)

You will need at least Delphi 2009 for that.

If you only want to save data files in the current ZeosLib 6.6.3 version, you might want to try to encode the filenames as UTF8.
That might currently work, but is not guaranteed to work.

--jeroen